# Why is my ref.current being null inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-portal

I am using `MUI Dialog` to render the modal and inside the `DialogContent`, I have a div that accepts the ref. When I try to access the `ref` inside my `useEffect`, it's null. Here is the code demonstration,

```
const Modal = () => {
  const myRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const node = myRef.current;
    // node is null
  }, []);

  return (
    <Dialog>
      <DialogContent>
        <div ref={myRef}></div>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  );
};
```

Af far as react life cycle goes, JSX is already rendered and ref is already set when the `useEffect` gets run. But, here, why is `myRef.current` being `null`? I tried using my own modal instead of MUI and it was working just fine. It works as expected. What is `MUI Dialog` doing here that I am not aware of and how can I fix it? Does it have anything to do with `MUI Dialog` being rendered inside the `Portal`? If so, how do I make it work? I can't put any dependencies inside the `useEffect`, it's important that `myRef.current` is available inside the `useEffect` on first mount.

Comment: Nope, in that question, op is not accessing the ref inside useEffect. So, it's expected that it's null. But, I am trying to use it inside `useEffect` and I don't understand why it's null

Comment: The code in the question seems to work for me when dropped into an online React playground. You may need to add more to create a reproducing example of the issue.

Comment: It works if we don't use `Dialog` from `MUI`. I am using `MUI Dialog`, so it's not working, at least on my end

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve with this code? `Dialog` seems to require `open` prop and it's pretty strange that you get no errors or warnings about it (but I suppose it's because you are using JSX without TypeScript), and I assume that since `Dialog` is not open it renders nothing, your `div` is not in DOM and hence it's `null`.

Comment: I just included very minimal of what I am trying to do. I am actually passing all the required props in my code. All I need is for the `myRef.current` to be available inside `useEffect` without having to provide any dependencies

Comment: In order to check if your `div` is in DOM while `Modal` is not open provide an `id` for it like `<div id="myRefDiv" ref={myRef} />` and then in browser console print `document.getElementById('myRefDiv')`. I bet you'll get `null` when `Dialog` is closed and an element when it's open.

Answer (score 0):

I provided `disablePortal` props to `Dialog` component and it's now working. In my case, `Dialog` is always open as soon as the component is mounted.